# Javascript Replace function confusion

Tags: javascript

I know this may go against the rules of SO, but their is a subject in JS that i just can not grasp. For example, when people use: `input.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')` I've tried using Google and i just can not find a website that explains this in a way to me which makes me understand it. If anybody could maybe link me somewhere or try explaining how that works, because it seems like a very important subject to learn about.

Thanks for all the help guys! I found a really great resource to use here if anybody ever runs into the same issue i did: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Are you asking how regular expressions work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: It's just whats inside of the input.replace() that confuses me. I'm currently using that chunk of code on my project but it bothers me when i'm using code i don't understand.

Comment: @user3890432: The 1st parameter is a "regular expression".

Comment: So you don't understand what `/[^\w\s]/gi` means?

Comment: What's inside there is a regular expression, and a replacement. That's why people are now giving you links that explain regular expressions.

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ You can check out what it matches at RegExPal (and experiment).

Comment: Will check out the links!

Comment: @CaseyFalk if we're all linking websites, I prefer the graphical representation you get on [**debuggex**](https://www.debuggex.com/). For people new to regular expressions, [**this page**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) my be useful too

Comment: @PaulS.: Rabin and Scott would be proud. Actually didn't know about Debuggex -- thanks for sharing! :) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)

Comment: A better source (than W3Schools) to learn about regular expression in general is http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html .

Answer (score 3):

This question is going to be closed, but let me take a moment to teach you how to think.

You have a function `replace` which takes two parameters. You should want to look up what type the parameters should be.

If you google "javascript replace", you'll see a link to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

On this page, you'll see that the first parameter is `regexp|substring`. In that explanation, there is a link to the **types** `RegExp` and `String`. You should be able to recognize that `/[^\w\s]/gi` is **not** a string and therefore *must* be a `RegExp`. You can follow [the link to the page on RegExp (Regular Expressions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and be enlightened.

---

Learning how to think about problems will not only help you ask better SO questions, it will also help you be a better programmer.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
/[^\w\s]/
```

Is a regular expression. It's matching anything that is NOT (that's what the `^` means in this context) a "word character" (`\w` - this includes letters, numbers and underscore) or whitespace (`\s`)

So if you have a string:

```
"hello *&&^( there"
```

And you run this replacement, it will give you

```
"hello  there"
```

the `gi` parts make it global (replace the whole string, not just the first occurance) and case insensitive (which in this case doesn't actually matter).

Check the links people have already suggested to learn more about regular expressions.